# Mobile Broadband missing in Loki

Tags: release-loki, networking, internet

Mobile Broadband is missing in network manager. Hardware is not detected. Updating kernel brings it partially back and makes configuration possible, but does not provide a selection option in network manager. Is there any specific reason for this?